# Mobile Safari bootstrap modal: Cursor in input field shows at the wrong place

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, safari, modal-dialog

I have a very simple bootstrap modal that is used for logging a user in. Only two fields (email and password). The problem is that when i trigger this modal and click on the email field the blinking text input cursor shows up at a wrong place while I type. It is above the input field (See first link). But if I click 'done' on the keyboard and then click the text field again it seems to be fine (See second link). If I close the modal the first time and open it again, the cursor is fine even then. It's just the first time load of this modal.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQsIF.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b38LN.png

```
<div class="login-logo sign-in-options">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 column sign-in-fields">
                                <button class="close" aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">
                                    x
                                </button>
                                <p class="register-page-header">
                                    Please Login.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 column sign-in-fields">
                                <input type="email" id="user-login-email" class="user-login-field" placeholder="Email" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 column sign-in-fields">
                                <input type="password" id="user-login-password" class="user-login-field" placeholder="Password" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 column sign-in-fields">
                                <a redirect="popup" onclick="displayIndexBAM(this);" class="become-member-link" href="#">Join</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 column sign-in-fields">
                                <a href="#" redirect="popup" onclick="displayForgotPassword(this);" class="forgot-password">Forgot Password?</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="login-loading"><img src="img/loading_transparent_medium.gif" alt="Loading" class="login-popup-loading">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <img alt="Login" class="login-button" redirect="popup" onclick="customerLogin(this);" src="img/login-button.png" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="login-failure-message">An error occurred while trying to process your request. Please try again later.</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="login-failure-other-messages" style="display:none;"></div>
                        </div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#user-login-email, #user-login-password, .user-register-field {
border: 0 none;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 10px;
width: 100%;
```

}

```
.notify-me input, #user-login-email, #user-login-password, .user-register-field, .user-forgot-field, .user-register-zipcode {
background-color: #E5E5E5;
box-shadow: none;
color: #000000;
display: block;
float: left;
margin-top: 5px;
```

}

Line height is set to inherit by BootStrap 3

Comment: Please show css , If you se lineheight for input field please remove it , Please ur show in jsfiddle.net

Comment: @ShibinRagh Added the CSS to the question. I have not explicitly specified any line height.

Comment: Please set height , Please use jsfiddle.net its more helpful